# Rails single include to multiple classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module

I have a module `DelayTasks` and many classes inside this module. I want to do include another module `DelayedEmails` to all classes in `DelayedTasks` just like the first class but with only one include. Is there a way to do so?

```rb
module DelayedTasks
  class A
    include DelayedEmails
  end

  class B
  end

  class C
  end

  class D
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you should be able to do:

```
module DelayedTasks

  class Base 
    include DelayedEmails
  end

  class A < Base
  end

  class B < Base
  end

  class C < Base
  end

  class D < Base
  end

end
```

BTW, defining multiple classes inside a single file does not seem like a good practice (IMO). Of course, it works. But, you might end up hunting around for where those classes are defined whereas if they are in separate files it might be a little bit more obvious where they are defined.

Answer (score -2):

### Solution 1 (Direct):

```
module DelayedTasks
  class A
  end

  class B
  end

  class C
  end

  class D
  end
end

DelayedTasks.constants.each do |constant|
  constant.include DelayedEmails if constant.is_a? Class
end
```

*However, because the file above is called line by line, then if there's another file that adds more classes inside the `DelayedTasks` module and that this file is loaded after the above code, then those classes won't be taken into consideration by the `.each` loop above, and thus they won't get `include` with `DelayedEmails`*

### Alternative Solution

*Assuming that why you ask this question in the first place is to avoid including multiple modules across all your classes...*

```
module DelayedTasks
  module Dependencies
    def self.included(base)
      base.include DelayedEmails
      # base.include SomeOtherModule1
      # base.include SomeOtherModule2
      # ...
    end
  end

  class A
    include Dependencies
  end

  class B
    include Dependencies
  end

  class C
    include Dependencies
  end
end
```

Comment: The OP stipulated "but with only one include". The second solution has an `include` in each class, which the OP is trying to avoid. No?

Comment: @jvillian Yes my Solution 1 is my direct answer. My Solution 2 is a possible answer to a 2nd probable question of the OP, in the assumption that probably he/she 1) intends to add multiple includes to the classes, hence why he/she asked the question in the first place, or 2) he/she would be benefit just by knowing that Solution 2 above is a possible approach he/she could use in the future. Though I could have gone with inheritance like what you did (which I would normally do, though...

Comment: I went with the include route (though i am aware that this contradicts OP's direct question of just using one include... is why I put it as Solution 2 instead), but that I still used `include` because this is what I felt natural to me, because the logic was "including" stuff, but not already necessary immediately requiring inheritance, and that there can only be one parent class and so I wanted my code to be  unobtrusive. Having said this though, probably I should have named: `Alternative Solution` instead of `Solution 2` to be more accurate of my intentions, and so I'll update my answer now.